# Find main diagonal in matrix - Scheme

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

I need to extract the main diagonal from a square matrix

```
(1 2 3)
(4 5 6) -> (1 5 9)
(7 8 9)
```

I have the following code and I need to replace the `...` with the appropriate functions.

```
(define (diag m)
  (if (null? m) '()
      (cons (... m)
            (diag (map ... (... m))))))
```

Input: `(diag '((1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9)))`
Output: `(1 5 9)`

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: The input is only one parameter - a list of lists. Example: (diag '((1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9)))

Comment: Are you sure that we need just to replace the sequence "..." ? I found another solution that I can show you.

Comment: Yes, you should replace "...". But if you have found out another solution, it would be interesting for me how it works :)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33367492/124319

Answer (score 1):

First of all I created a function that returns n-th element of list (I am not sure if you can use built-in function for it, that's why I created my own bicycle):

```
(define (nthItem l item currentItem)
    (if (null? l) '()
      (if (= currentItem item) (car l)
        (nthItem (cdr l) item (+ currentItem 1)))))
```

Then I created a function that you need. I added a parameter "i" that contains current position on a diagonal:

```
(define (diagPrivate m i)
  (if (null? m) '()
    (cons (nthItem (car m) i 0)
      (diagPrivate (cdr m) (+ i 1)))))
```

For better appearance I created a wrapper for this function (that looks like your initial function):

```
(define (diag m)
    (diagPrivate m 0))
```

Comment: Lisp is seldom written with `camelCase` but `lisp-case`. One of scheme primitives is called `list-ref` that does the same as `nth-item`. Your version is O(n^2) time while the OP had O(n)

Answer (score 1):

So you are asking, given you have the list `'((1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9))` how do I get the value `1` from it?

Then you are asking given the same list, how do I get `((4 5 6) (7 8 9))` from it.

Then given that result how do I make a new list using `map` that only takes the rest of each element list so that the result is `((5 6) (8 9))`

The question code looks like came from SO as an answer with **VERY** easy challenge on how to complete it. Am I right?

The answer is of course just list accessors every beginner schemer should know: `cdr` x 2 and `caar`, not necessarily in that order.

Comment: Input: (diag '((1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9))) Output: (1 5 9)

Comment: @K.H. I didn't quite get your comment but you have understood my answer. In the recursion when you have `((1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9))` you need to fetch `1` and recur with `((5 6) (8 9))`

Comment: Right. The last two lines from the question above will look like this: (cons (caar m) (diag (map cdr (cdr m)))).

Comment: @K.H. Correct. The code you have is elegant. I wouldn't use lists to represent matrices but it works great in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Using Racket which is a Scheme dialect:

```
(define diag '((1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9)))

(define (getDiagonal l)
  (let loop ((l l)
             (ol '())
             (n 0))
    (cond
      [(empty? l) (reverse ol)]
      [(loop (rest l) 
             (cons (list-ref (first l) n) ol) 
             (add1 n))])))

(getDiagonal diag)
```

Output:

```
'(1 5 9)
```

There is `for/list` loop in Racket which also can be used here:

```
(for/list ((i (length diag)))
  (list-ref (list-ref diag i) i))
```